# Is Debian Minimal a good starting point for a VPS?

Tags: vps, debian-wheezy

When I reinstall Debian 7 Wheezy on my VPS I can choose between Minimal and Normal Debian 7 image.
I tried both and found that the Minimal image does not contain, for example, the sudo command and configured iptables.

Where can I find detailed information about the difference in installed and/or configured packages between the normal image and the minimal image?

Comment: Good edit, wish more users would do this.

Comment: You may be confusing the ISO images with the install packages selected by [`tasksel`](https://wiki.debian.org/tasksel).  You can install a full Debian desktop from the minimal ISO if you choose to in the Software Selection step. If your VPS provider has a deployment named "debian minimal" (not a CD ISO), then they would have to tell you which packages/options they used to build the image.

Comment: You are probably right. If you like put this in an answer and I will accept it.